# Existence of a generic filter $G$ such that $p\in G$ and Axiom of choice

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, forcing

When we prove that "If $M$ is countable, $(P,\le)$ is a partial order and $p\in P$, then there is a $G$ that is $P$-generic over $M$ such that $p\in G$", the axiom of (countable) choice should be used?

If we let $M$ be a transitive set, then we can prove this without using the axiom of countable choice.

But I don't know whether the axiom should be used to prove the general case.

Comment: What difference would transitivity make?  Does your proof in that case actually use transitivity?

Comment: If $M$ is a countable transitive set, the union of all dense subsets of $P$ which are in $M$ is countable. Then we can use a well order of this union to construct a generic filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The fact that $M$ is countable is already enough, at least assuming that $M$ is a model of [enough] set theory.

The reason here is that it is enough to find a generic filter on the partial order $P\cap M$, which is a countable set. So we can enumerate it, $\{p_n\mid n<\omega\}$ and since $M$ is countable, $\{D\in M\mid D\subseteq P\text{ is dense}\}$ is countable, and we can enumerate it as $\{D_n\mid n<\omega\}$. And now the usual thing works: recursively construct $G$ by taking the least possible condition in $D_n$.

If we do not assume that $M$ is countable, then the axiom of choice *might* come into play, but there's more finesse to this, and it's best to set this aside for now.